# Domestic cleaning products and types of solvents

Tags: everyday-chemistry

I have a floor cleaner which washes and vacuums the floortiles.   The instructions advise not to use solvent cleaners with it.  My understanding is that even water is a solvent.  The manufacturers/agents will just try to sell me their product.  I want to use cheap domestic solutions (eg. Sugar Soap, Pinoclean, Bar Keepers Friend).    Can anyone advise please? At present I use just hot water, sodium bicarbonate ($\ce{NaHCO3}$) and vinegar of a small amount of washing up liquid.   Thanks.

Comment: The manufacturer likely means that solvents shouldn't be use.  Solvents likely stands for non water based detergents and stuff such a varnish removers...

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways of cleaners. Ones that will *"grab on to"* the dirt and bacteria to wash it away e.g. soap and shampoo. Then there are ones that will dissolve the dirt and kill the bacteria such as bleaches. They won't do anything dangerous together, they'll just not work.